# How would I return to the input in this while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to get this to loop back to the input if the input is invalid.

```
if(userSelection == 'G') {
     String genderPrompt = "Please enter animal's gender\n" + "Male\n" + "Female";
     System.out.println(genderPrompt);
     String animalGender = readInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                    
     System.out.println(animalGender);
                    
     while(!animalGender.equals("male") && !animalGender.equals("female")) {
          System.out.println("Invalid Selection.");
          System.out.println(genderPrompt);
     }
                    
     animal.setGender(animalGender);
     System.out.println("Animal Gender has been set to " + animal.getGender());
```

Comment: You don't have to concatenate the strings with `"Please enter animal's gender\n" + "Male\n" + "Female"`, you can just do `"Please enter animal's gender\nMale\nFemale"` directly. But can't you just copy the input to the end of the loop body?

Comment: I get an infinite loop with an invalid entry
Thanks for the tip on the string.

Comment: I would suggest the same. I wouldn't mind the code duplicate, since it's just one line and  the two inputs belong to two different logic blocks. Your code right now just prints the error without asking again for input.

Comment: Okay, you should put that information in the question. You shouldn't get an infinite loop if you include the line at the bottom of the while-loop, so are you sure you're updating the `animalGender` variable properly?

Comment: If entered correctly, it works properly. If I add the line to the bottom of the while-loop, it get a duplicate local variable genderPrompt

Comment: @Sam It sounds then like you're trying to create a new variable with the same name instead of updating the existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you create a while loop, you need to edit or update the variable so that the condition will eventually become false, otherwise the loop will continue infinitely.

Since your while loop runs depending on the value of `animalGender`, it would make sense to update `animalGender` by taking in user input inside the while loop. By doing this, if the user's `animalGender` is invalid, we output that there is an error and ask them for another input:

```
while (!animalGender.equals("male") && !animalGender.equals("female")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Selection.");
    System.out.println(genderPrompt);
    animalGender = readInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (userSelection.equals("G")) {   
    String animalGender;
            
    do {              
        String genderPrompt = "Please enter animal's gender \nMale \nFemale";
        System.out.println(genderPrompt);
        animalGender = sc.next().toLowerCase();
    } while (!animalGender.equals("male") && !animalGender.equals("female"));

     animal.setGender(animalGender);
     System.out.println("Animal Gender has been set to " + animal.getGender());                
}
```